# `hasAmbiguousLayout` is true but `exerciseAmbiguityInLayout()` does nothing?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a vertical `UIStackView` giving me an ambiguous layout runtime warning:

> Height and vertical position are ambiguous for UIStackView

I've tried calling `exerciseAmbiguityInLayout` on the view in question but nothing happens. Does this mean my layout is not actually ambiguous? Or does `exerciseAmbiguityInLayout` just not work sometimes?

The layout in question is extremely complex with multiple nested stack views in both orientations, so I can't really post it here. But I'm looking for a sanity check on what `exerciseAmbiguityInLayout()` is supposed to do when `hasAmbiguousLayout` is true.

Comment: Are you seeing this in Debug View Hierarchy? Or as a warning message in the console?

Comment: It's in Debug View Hierarchy as a runtime issue. But I confirmed that `hasAmbiguousLayout` is true for the view in question.

Comment: Interesting... I tried a number of conflicting / ambiguous constraints and then calling `.exerciseAmbiguityInLayout()` but not seeing anything happen. But... I then gave a `UIView` width constraints of `greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 120.0` and `lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 300.0`. So, both constraints can be satisfied, but with no intrinsic size, the width is `ambiguous`. With those constraints, calling `exerciseAmbiguityInLayout()` ***did*** give me visual feedback, switching the view  between 120 and 300 pt widths. So --- I expect it will only work with *some* ambiguities.